# Using Macro to generate combinations over multiple columns

Tags: vba

According to =COMBIN(20,6), 38,760 possible combinations exist.

I need to run a macro that can list all the possible combinations over 6 columns.

So I need the first 6,460 combinations in column A, the next 6,460 combinations in column B etc. all the way to column F. How do I do this using VBA?

Comment: It is easy to do with a recursion, however what exactly do you want to show in the cells? Names, Characters, Numbers?

Comment: I want it to show numbers

Comment: Like 1,2,3,4,5,6 ... 1,12,13,14,15,16, ... 1,16,17,18,19,20 ... etc.?

Comment: Yes. Column A would start 1,2,3,4,5,6 and then the next row would be 1,2,3,4,5,7 and then 1,2,3,4,5,8 etc

Answer (score 0):

This is working VB-Code, I assume you will be able to put the results into excel-cells yourself... :)

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    'This is the call that inits the recursion
    CombineNumbers 20, 6
End Sub

Private Function CombineNumbers(Num_Elements As Long, Num_Selected As Long) As String()
    Dim Buff() As String
    ReDim Buff(BinomCoeff(Num_Elements, Num_Selected) - 1)

    CombineNumbersRecursion 1, Num_Elements, Num_Selected, Buff, 0&

    Dim Value

    For Each Value In Buff
        Debug.Print Value
    Next Value

End Function

Private Sub CombineNumbersRecursion(Start_Element As Long, End_Element As Long, _
    Num_Selected As Long, Buff() As String, BuffStartIndex As Long, _
    Optional CurrStr As String = vbNullString)

    If (Num_Selected) Then
        'Recursion
        Dim i As Long

        For i = Start_Element To End_Element
            CombineNumbersRecursion i + 1, End_Element, Num_Selected - 1&, Buff, _
                BuffStartIndex, IIf(Len(CurrStr), CurrStr & ", " & CStr(i), CStr(i))
        Next i
    Else
        'Break recursion
        Buff(BuffStartIndex) = CurrStr
        BuffStartIndex = BuffStartIndex + 1&
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub

Private Function BinomCoeff(n As Long, k As Long) As Long

    Dim i As Long

    BinomCoeff = 1&

    For i = 1& To k
        BinomCoeff = BinomCoeff * ((n + 1& - i&) / i&)
    Next i

End Function
```

Regards,

AKDA